# How can I assign an array of elements to one index in Series. Is there any possible way of doing as a Series object in Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Suppose I have indexes like

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
```

And also I have arrays like

```
b = np.array([11,12,13,14,15])
c = np.array([21,22,23,24,25])
d = np.array([31,32,33,34,35])
e = np.array([41,42,43,44,45])
```

I want to get an output as a Series object like:

```
1    [11,12,13,14,15]
2    [21,22,23,24,25]
3    [31,32,33,34,35]
4    [41,42,43,44,45]
```

Comment: Your expected output looks nothing like a `series` object.

Comment: I don't understand how the indexes relate to the arrays or the final series

Comment: Sorry Changed the question now